# Add Three New Planning Variables To Nurse Roster Solution

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I am trying to add three new planning variables to Optaplanner Nurse Roster Solution. These three planning variables were shortTask, mainTask, and fullTask which are a ShiftTaskAllocation class :

```
public class ShiftTaskAllocation extends AbstractPersistable {

   private Task task;
   private Shift shift;
   private ShiftAssignment shiftAssignment;

   .... // getter and setter methods and other complex methods 
}
```

Here is the Task class :

```
public class Task extends AbstractPersistable {
   private String code;
   private String description;

   .... // getter and setter methods and other complex methods 
}
```

Here is the task skill requirement class, a class that hold information about what skill that required in order to finish a task :

```
public class TaskSkillRequirement extends AbstractPersistable { 
   private Task task;
   private Skill skill;

   .... // getter and setter methods and other complex methods 
}
```

Here is the skill proficiency class, a class that hold information for what skills that an employee has :

```
public class SkillProficiency extends AbstractPersistable {

   private Employee employee;
   private List<Skill> skillList;

   .... // getter and setter methods and other complex methods 
}
```

The idea is for each shift, we could setup some task that need to be done in that particular shift. 
Here is my planning entity class that already modified to fit this requirement :

```
public class ShiftAssignment extends AbstractPersistable {
   private Shift shift;
   private int indexInShift;

   // Planning variables: changes during planning, between score calculations.
   private Employee employee;
   private ShiftTaskAllocation shortTask;
   private ShiftTaskAllocation mainTask;
   private ShiftTaskAllocation fullTask;

   .... // getter and setter methods and other complex methods 

   @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"shiftTaskAllocationRange"}, nullable = true, strengthComparatorClass = ShiftTaskAllocationStrengthComparator.class)
   public ShiftTaskAllocation getShortTask() {
      return shortTask;
   }

   @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"shiftTaskAllocationRange"}, nullable = true, strengthComparatorClass = ShiftTaskAllocationStrengthComparator.class)
   public ShiftTaskAllocation getMainTask() {
      return mainTask;
   }

   @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"shiftTaskAllocationRange"}, nullable = true, strengthComparatorClass = ShiftTaskAllocationStrengthComparator.class)
   public ShiftTaskAllocation getFullTask() {
      return fullTask;
   }

   public int getSumOfTasks() {
      int sum = 0;

      if (shortTask != null) {
         sum += shortTask.getTask().getType().getValue();
      }

      if (mainTask != null) {
         sum += mainTask.getTask().getType().getValue();
      }

      if (fullTask != null) {
         sum += fullTask.getTask().getType().getValue();
      }

      return sum;
   }
}
```

Here is the TaskType enum :

```
public enum TaskType {
   SHORT(1), MAIN(2), FULL(3);

   private final int value;

   private TaskType(int value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }
}
```

In one shift, the employee should be working on a short task + main task only, or a full task only. 
What rules that I need to create in order to make sure optaplanner could correctly assigned task and employee to a shift? 
Any help or comment would be appreciated. 
Thanks and regards.

**

### Update 1

**

I have tried to write some rules, to guide optaplanner find the feasible solution. The rules that I think I need to write down are :

1. A ShiftTaskAllocation could be assigned to one ShiftAssignment only (no duplicates)
2. All ShiftTaskAllocation must be assigned (no ShiftTaskAllocation that unassigned to ShiftAssignment)
3. A ShiftTaskAllocation should be assigned to appropriate shift (e.g. if ShiftTaskAllocation for morning shift, should be only assigned to ShiftAssignment that has a morning shift).
4. Sum Tasks of ShiftAssignment should be exact 3 (whether shortTask + mainTask or fullTask only)
5. No unmatched skill for employee assignment (for all shortTask, mainTask, or fullTask)
6. Only task with type SHORT that can be assigned to shortTask
7. Only task with type MAIN that can be assigned to mainTask
8. Only task with type FULL that can be assigned to fullTask

Here is the rules that I have tried to write down on my own :

```
############################################################################
// Hard constraints
############################################################################

// a nurse can only work one shift per day, i.e. no two shift can be assigned to the same nurse on a day.
rule "oneShiftPerDay"
    when
        $s1 : ShiftAssignment(employee != null,   
            $leftId : id, $employee : employee, $shiftDate : shiftDate)
        $s2 : ShiftAssignment(employee == $employee, shiftDate == $shiftDate, id > $leftId)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// a short shift task can only assigned to one shift only.
rule "oneShortShiftTaskPerShiftAssignment"
    when
        $s1 : ShiftAssignment(shortTask != null,    
            $leftId : id, $shortTask : shortTask)
        $s2 : ShiftAssignment(shortTask == $shortTask, id != $leftId)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// a main shift task can only assigned to one shift only.
rule "oneMainShiftTaskPerShiftAssignment"
    when
        $s1 : ShiftAssignment(mainTask != null,    
            $leftId : id, $mainTask : mainTask)
        $s2 : ShiftAssignment(mainTask == $mainTask, id != $leftId)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// a full shift task can only assigned to one shift only.
rule "oneFullShiftTaskPerShiftAssignment"
    when
        $s1 : ShiftAssignment(fullTask != null,    
            $leftId : id, $fullTask : fullTask)
        $s2 : ShiftAssignment(fullTask == $fullTask, id != $leftId)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// a short task can only assigned to one shift assignment
rule "allShiftTaskAllocationMustBeAssigned"
    when
        ShiftTaskAllocation(shiftAssignment == null)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// a short shift task assignment must assigned to appropriate shift.
rule "shortShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment"
    when
        ShiftAssignment(shortTask != null, shortTask.shift != shift)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// a main shift task assignment must assigned to appropriate shift.
rule "mainShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment"
    when
        ShiftAssignment(mainTask != null, mainTask.shift != shift)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// a full shift task assignment must assigned to appropriate shift.
rule "fullShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment"
    when
        ShiftAssignment(fullTask != null, fullTask.shift != shift)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// sum of tasks on a shift is lower than 3.
rule "sumTasksOfShiftLowerThan3"
    when
        $s1 : ShiftAssignment(sumOfTasks < 3, $sumOfTasks : sumOfTasks)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $sumOfTasks - 3);
end

// sum of tasks on a shift is higher than 3.
rule "sumTasksOfShiftHigherThan3"
    when
        $s1 : ShiftAssignment(sumOfTasks > 3, $sumOfTasks : sumOfTasks)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 3- $sumOfTasks);
end

// a nurse can't be assigned to short and main task that he/she didn't has the skill to do it
rule "noUnmatchedSkillEmployeeAssignmentToShortMainTask"
    when 
        ShiftAssignment( employee != null, 
            $employee : employee, shortTask != null, mainTask != null, fullTask == null, 
            $shortTask : shortTask, $mainTask : mainTask )

        not ( forall ( TaskSkillRequirement( $shortTask.task == task, $skill : skill ),
                 SkillProficiency( employee == $employee, skillList contains $skill ) 
              )
            )

        not ( forall ( TaskSkillRequirement( $mainTask.task == task, $skill : skill ),
                 SkillProficiency( employee == $employee, skillList contains $skill ) 
              )
            )       
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// a nurse can't be assigned to full task that he/she didn't has the skill to do it
rule "noUnmatchedSkillEmployeeAssignmentToFullTask"
    when 
        ShiftAssignment( employee != null, 
            $employee : employee, shortTask == null, mainTask == null, fullTask != null, 
            $fullTask : fullTask )

        not ( forall ( TaskSkillRequirement( $fullTask.task == task, $skill : skill ),
                 SkillProficiency( employee == $employee, skillList contains $skill ) 
              )
            )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// only task with type SHORT that can be assigned to shortTask
rule "noUmatchedShortTaskAssignment"
    when
        ShiftAssignment(shortTask != null, shortTask.task.type.value != 1, $shortValue : shortTask.task.type.value, 
            shortTask.shift != shift)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $shortValue * -1);
end

// only task with type MAIN that can be assigned to mainTask
rule "noUmatchedMainTaskAssignment"
    when
        ShiftAssignment(mainTask != null, mainTask.task.type.value != 2, $mainValue : mainTask.task.type.value, 
            mainTask.shift != shift)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $mainValue * -1);
end

// only task with type FULLL that can be assigned to fullTask
rule "noUmatchedFullTaskAssignment"
    when
        ShiftAssignment(fullTask != null, fullTask.task.type.value != 3, $fullValue : fullTask.task.type.value, 
            fullTask.shift != shift)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $fullValue * -1);
end
```

But when I tried to run solving phase using a simple sample dataset (the solving phase was run for 2 minutes), it produce only an unfeasible solution like this :

```
2017-04-14 05:52:11,276 [main] INFO  KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-04-14 05:52:12,300 [main] DEBUG Starting Engine in PHREAK mode
2017-04-14 05:52:12,923 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent (273), best score (uninitialized/-30hard/-75soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2017-04-14 05:52:24,265 [main] DEBUG     CH step (0), time spent (11616), score (-28hard/-74soft), selected move count (49130), picked move ([2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => DAI(Daisy), 2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => ShiftTaskAllocation-63, 2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => null, 2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => null]).
2017-04-14 05:52:32,375 [main] DEBUG     CH step (1), time spent (19726), score (-26hard/-73soft), selected move count (49130), picked move ([2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => HAN(Hanks), 2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => ShiftTaskAllocation-73, 2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => null, 2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => null]).
2017-04-14 05:52:39,478 [main] DEBUG     CH step (2), time spent (26829), score (-24hard/-73soft), selected move count (49130), picked move ([2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => ANT(Anton), 2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => ShiftTaskAllocation-68, 2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => null, 2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@null => null]).
2017-04-14 05:52:45,838 [main] DEBUG     CH step (3), time spent (33189), score (-22hard/-73soft), selected move count (49130), picked move ([2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => CHR(Christine), 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => ShiftTaskAllocation-74, 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => null, 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => null]).
2017-04-14 05:52:51,926 [main] DEBUG     CH step (4), time spent (39277), score (-21hard/-72soft), selected move count (49130), picked move ([2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => FRA(Frans), 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => null, 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => ShiftTaskAllocation-64, 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => null]).
2017-04-14 05:52:57,902 [main] DEBUG     CH step (5), time spent (45253), score (-20hard/-71soft), selected move count (49130), picked move ([2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => IRE(Irene), 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => null, 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => ShiftTaskAllocation-65, 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => null]).
2017-04-14 05:53:03,956 [main] DEBUG     CH step (6), time spent (51307), score (-19hard/-70soft), selected move count (49130), picked move ([2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => JUS(Justin), 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => null, 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => ShiftTaskAllocation-69, 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@null => null]).
2017-04-14 05:53:10,393 [main] DEBUG     CH step (7), time spent (57744), score (-18hard/-70soft), selected move count (49130), picked move ([2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => BRA(Brandon), 2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => null, 2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => ShiftTaskAllocation-70, 2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => null]).
2017-04-14 05:53:15,975 [main] DEBUG     CH step (8), time spent (63326), score (-17hard/-70soft), selected move count (49130), picked move ([2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => EMI(Emily), 2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => null, 2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => ShiftTaskAllocation-75, 2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => null]).
2017-04-14 05:53:21,517 [main] DEBUG     CH step (9), time spent (68867), score (-16hard/-70soft), selected move count (49130), picked move ([2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => GEO(George), 2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => null, 2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => ShiftTaskAllocation-76, 2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@null => null]).
2017-01-01-MORN : DAI(Daisy) : Blood Test(63)
2017-01-01-MORN : HAN(Hanks) : Blood Test(73)
2017-01-01-MORN : ANT(Anton) : Urine Test(68)
2017-01-01-AFNO : CHR(Christine) : Urine Test(74)
2017-01-01-AFNO : FRA(Frans) : Clean Patient(64)
2017-01-01-AFNO : IRE(Irene) : Clean Patient(65)
2017-01-01-AFNO : JUS(Justin) : Clean Patient(69)
2017-01-01-NIGH : BRA(Brandon) : Clean Patient(70)
2017-01-01-NIGH : EMI(Emily) : Clean Patient(75)
2017-01-01-NIGH : GEO(George) : Clean Patient(76)
2017-04-14 05:53:21,519 [main] INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (10), time spent (68870), best score (-16hard/-70soft).
2017-04-14 05:53:22,327 [main] DEBUG     LS step (0), time spent (69678), score (-16hard/-70soft),     best score (-16hard/-70soft), accepted/selected move count (800/800), picked move (2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@DAI(Daisy) <=> 2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@ANT(Anton)).
2017-04-14 05:53:22,783 [main] DEBUG     LS step (1), time spent (70134), score (-16hard/-70soft),     best score (-16hard/-70soft), accepted/selected move count (800/993), picked move (2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@IRE(Irene) => ShiftTaskAllocation-71).
2017-04-14 05:53:23,176 [main] DEBUG     LS step (2), time spent (70527), score (-16hard/-70soft),     best score (-16hard/-70soft), accepted/selected move count (800/1152), picked move ([[2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@FRA(Frans)] => JUS(Justin), [2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@JUS(Justin)] => FRA(Frans)]).
2017-04-14 05:53:23,522 [main] DEBUG     LS step (3), time spent (70873), score (-16hard/-70soft),     best score (-16hard/-70soft), accepted/selected move count (800/1195), picked move (2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@JUS(Justin) => ShiftTaskAllocation-66).
2017-04-14 05:53:23,886 [main] DEBUG     LS step (4), time spent (71237), score (-16hard/-70soft),     best score (-16hard/-70soft), accepted/selected move count (800/1452), picked move ([[2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@BRA(Brandon)] => IRE(Irene), [2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@IRE(Irene)] => BRA(Brandon)]).
2017-04-14 05:53:24,326 [main] DEBUG     LS step (5), time spent (71677), score (-16hard/-70soft),     best score (-16hard/-70soft), accepted/selected move count (800/1508), picked move (2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@FRA(Frans) <=> 2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@GEO(George)).
..........
2017-04-14 05:54:08,226 [main] DEBUG     LS step (69), time spent (115577), score (-16hard/-70soft),     best score (-16hard/-70soft), accepted/selected move count (800/5125), picked move (2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@DAI(Daisy) <=> 2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@EMI(Emily)).
2017-04-14 05:54:10,613 [main] DEBUG     LS step (70), time spent (117964), score (-16hard/-70soft),     best score (-16hard/-70soft), accepted/selected move count (800/13436), picked move ([[2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@CHR(Christine)] => IRE(Irene), [2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@IRE(Irene)] => CHR(Christine)]).
2017-04-14 05:54:12,649 [main] DEBUG     LS step (71), time spent (120000), score (-16hard/-70soft),     best score (-16hard/-70soft), accepted/selected move count (591/10978), picked move ([[2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@DAI(Daisy)] => EMI(Emily), [2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@EMI(Emily)] => DAI(Daisy)]).
2017-04-14 05:54:12,649 [main] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: step total (72), time spent (120000), best score (-16hard/-70soft).
2017-04-14 05:54:12,649 [main] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (120000), best score (-16hard/-70soft), average calculate count per second (6544), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
```

Matched constraint :

```
mainShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment=-6
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/mainShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@GEO(George)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/mainShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@EMI(Emily)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/mainShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@BRA(Brandon)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/mainShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@JUS(Justin)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/mainShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@IRE(Irene)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/mainShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@FRA(Frans)]=-1
fullShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment=-4
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/fullShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@CHR(Christine)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/fullShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@ANT(Anton)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/fullShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@HAN(Hanks)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/fullShiftTaskAssignmentMustAssignedToAppropriateShiftAssignment/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_MORN@DAI(Daisy)]=-1
sumTasksOfShiftLowerThan3=-6
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/sumTasksOfShiftLowerThan3/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@GEO(George)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/sumTasksOfShiftLowerThan3/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@EMI(Emily)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/sumTasksOfShiftLowerThan3/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_NIGH@BRA(Brandon)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/sumTasksOfShiftLowerThan3/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@JUS(Justin)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/sumTasksOfShiftLowerThan3/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@IRE(Irene)]=-1
org.optaplanner.webexamples.nurserostering.rest.solver/sumTasksOfShiftLowerThan3/level0/[2017-01-01(Sun)_AFNO@FRA(Frans)]=-1
```

I was confuse now, why is optaplanner produce an unfeasible solution, no matter how long I give the time, it just still produce an unfeasible solution. Does anybody know, what is the root cause of this problem? Thanks and regards.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?